Solve 1 Exponential Equation With 3 Initial Conditions
I have an exponential equation,
$$
\begin{align}
  y = A - Be^{kx}
\end{align}
$$
where $(x,y) = (0,3500)$, $(x,y) = (6600,100)$, and $(x,y) = (6000,1000)$ are the initial conditions (IC).

I tried solving it with Python's sympy and the package's algorithm did not "converge;" I then tried using the Wolfram Alpha website and obtained,
$$
\begin{align}
 \begin{cases}
   A = 3400.56 \\
   B = 99.4402 \\
   k = 0.00053065 
 \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
However, this cannot be my answer since I know the $y$-intercept is $y = 3500$ according to my first listed IC in my problem.

Note that for both sympy's solve method and Wolfram Alpha's calculator, the three equations I used were:
$$
\begin{align}
  &3500 = A - B \\
  &6600 = k^{-1}\ln\left[\frac{A-100}{B}\right] \\
  &6000 = k^{-1}\ln\left[\frac{A - 1000}{B}\right]
\end{align}
$$
Maybe the reason it is not giving me a desired answer is because Wolfam is not considering $k = 0$ when according to the exponential equation it can be such that $k = 0$? Even an approximate solution would satisfy my bigger issue, but I have failed to also solve it.

If you can program in Python, instead on relying on the ability of the solve routine to find the solution of any system of equations fed to it in any form, which it does not possess, just think for 5 minutes and write your own code using bisection (8 lines) or Newton (a bit longer). It will be easier, faster, and way more educational ;-)

The reported results are wrong. Eliminate $A$ and $B$ from the first and second equations. You are left with a simple equation in $k$. Solved with my phone.

Taking help from the comments,
From the equation $y=A-Be^{kx}$, we have three equations:
$$A-B=3500$$
$$100=A-Be^{6600k}$$
$$1000=A-Be^{6000k}$$
Putting $A=3500+B$ in the second equation, we get:
$$100=3500+B-Be^{6600k}\Rightarrow B(e^{6600k}-1)=3400$$
Therefore,
$$B=\frac{3400}{e^{6600k}-1}$$
Now, in the third equation, we have:
$$1000=3500+B-Be^{6000k}\Rightarrow B(e^{6000k}-1)=2500$$
and again:
$$B=\frac{2500}{e^{6000k}-1}$$
Equating both the equations, we have:
$$\frac{3400}{e^{6600k}-1}=\frac{2500}{e^{6000k}-1}$$
$$\frac{34}{25}=\frac{e^{6600k}-1}{e^{6000k}-1}$$
$$e^{6600k}-1=1.36e^{6000k}-1.36$$
$$1.36e^{6000k}-e^{6600k}=0.36$$
Solving numerically [I do not have any analytical solution], the value of $k$ is found approximately to be $k=0$ and $k=0.000489$. But setting $k=0$ makes our initial equation $\frac{3400}{e^{6600k}-1}=\frac{2500}{e^{6000k}-1}$ undefined. So $k\neq0$.
Setting this value of $k$ in the equation $B=\frac{3400}{e^{6600k}-1}$, we get: $B=140.414$ and then $A=3640.414$.
Tell me if anything's wrong.

This is perfect, when I plot it, it gives me the curve I need. I enjoyed and learned from reading your solution.
